# Adjusting the frame of a SwiftUI view with a DragGesture resizes it in all dimensions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to implement a simple view in SwiftUI that can be resized via a drag handle placed on its lower-left corner. The resizable view's dimensions are set via two @State variables controlling the width and height. These variables are mutated within a DragGesture's onChanged handler captured by the drag handle.

It's sort of working, but not in the way I expect. When I perform a drag gesture on the drag handle, the view gets resized in all dimensions. I want the resizing to work in the same way as a desktop window; dragging shouldn't resize the view in all directions.

Below is a recording from the iOS simulator showing the incorrect behaviour:

[image: Resizing the view]

I understand that the centre of a SwiftUI view is considered its origin, and that's probably what's causing this behaviour. I'm not sure how to work around this.

Here's my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // Initialise to a size proportional to the screen dimensions.
    @State private var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3.5
    @State private var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 1.5
    
    var body: some View {
        // This is the view that's going to be resized.
        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
            // This is the "drag handle" positioned on the lower-left corner of this stack.
            Text("")
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .background(.red)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            // Enforce minimum dimensions.
                            width = max(100, width + value.translation.width)
                            height = max(100, height + value.translation.height)
                        }
                )
        }
        .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .center)
        .border(.red, width: 5)
        .background(.yellow)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Edit**: I was too liberal in what I removed for the minimal example above. The following snippet adds a `position` constraint on the ZStack, which is used in another gesture (not shown) so the view can be dragged around.

I'm guessing this is problematic because `position` specifies relative coordinates from the centre of the ZStack to the parent VStack, and as the ZStack is resized, it's being "moved" to maintain the position constraint.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // Initialise to a size proportional to the screen dimensions.
    @State private var width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3.5
    @State private var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 1.5
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // This is the view that's going to be resized.
            ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .frame(width: width, height: height)
                // This is the "drag handle" positioned on the lower-left corner of this stack.
                Text("")
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .background(.red)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                // Enforce minimum dimensions.
                                width = max(100, width + value.translation.width)
                                height = max(100, height + value.translation.height)
                            }
                    )
            }
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
            .border(.red, width: 5)
            .background(.yellow)
            .padding()
            // This position constraint causes the ZStack to grow/shrink in all dimensions
            // when resized.
            .position(x: 400, y: 400)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right that the issue is caused by your view being center-aligned.

To fix this, you can wrap your view in a `VStack` with a different alignment applied, e.g. `.topLeading` if you want it to align to the top-left.

You also have to make sure this `VStack` is taking up the available space of the view. Otherwise, it will shrink to the size of your resizable box, causing the view to stay center-aligned. You can achieve this with `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)`.

### TL;DR

Place your resizable box in a `VStack` with a `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)` modifier.

```
VStack { // <-- Wrapping VStack with alignment modifier
    // This is the view that's going to be resized.
    ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .frame(width: width, height: height)
        // This is the "drag handle" positioned on the lower-left corner of this stack.
        Text("")
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .background(.red)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        // Enforce minimum dimensions.
                        width = max(100, width + value.translation.width)
                        height = max(100, height + value.translation.height)
                    }
            )
    }
    .frame(width: width, height: height, alignment: .topLeading)
    .border(.red, width: 5)
    .background(.yellow)
    .padding()
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
```

### Edit

With an additional `position` modifier on the ZStack, try offsetting the `x` and `y` values by half of the `width` and `height` to position relative to the top-left origin of the ZStack:

```
.position(x: 400 + width / 2, y: 400 + height / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and works as expected! I may have been a bit liberal in creating my minimal example though; my actual app constrains the ZStack with a `position`, and wrapping it with a VStack as suggested doesn't appear to work. I've updated my original question with a better minimal example.

Comment: @disposedtrolley I updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you. :)